# How many ways $8$ persons be seated around a circular table facing the center such that $3$ particular persons are always together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways $8$ persons be seated around a circular table facing the center such that $3$ particular persons are always together?

> My approach:
>   Bcoz 3 particular persons have to be together, I bundled them into one box.
>   Now before putting then into box I'll first have to select those 3 out of 8 people so it would be done in $$8C3$$ ways.
>   (..am I wrong???)
>   Now there are in all $$(8-3) + 1 = 5 + 1 = 6$$ entities.
>   So these can be arranged across a circular table in $$(6-1)! =5!$$ Ways.
>   And the $3$ people in box can be arranged in $$3!=6$$ ways
>   So total case would be = $$8C3.(5!)(6)$$

Now the problem is:
My professor is saying that there won't be any term like $8C3$.  And as per my professor the answer is just $$(5!).6$$
But I think we would also have to select first $3$ people out of $8$ right...?(is my thinking right..??)
And then perform circular permutation.
Like ..wouldn't the selection of $3$ people at the very first place in this problem be a problem that we need to take into consideration...???

Okay if I consider that bcoz problem statement has the term "particular" in it we won't consider 8C3 
But plz help some one convincing me if in case I have a term say "**any** 3 person together"..then would I not have 8C3 in this case..???

Comment: Your professor is correct.  The particular people are given.  Therefore, we do not have to select them.

Comment: Okay...so say in the  problem statement, instead of "particular" if they would have used the term "any" ...then still I won't have 8C3...??(plz correct if I am wrong..)

Comment: It would be difficult to phrase the question to get your answer, which is why the problem is phrased as it is.

Comment: Your answer comes to $8!$, which completely ignores the "$3$ particular persons" condition. So it must be wrong. (Also it treats rotated arrangements as different, whereas the question implies that they are to be counted just once.)

Comment: @TonyK ok I got it thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes answer will be $(5!).3!$ since according to the question they are particular 3 people who will sit together we are not required to select ( selecting any way is meaningless as always any 3 are together ).
$$ $$
Considering $3$ to be one unit we need to arrange $(8-3+1)=6$ in $(5!)$ number of ways now the $3$ together can arrange themself in $3!$ number of ways in every arrangement of 6.
$$ Total \,arrangements = (5!)(3!)$$

Comment: Okay...so you mean to say that if at all the problem had "any" instead of "particular"...I won't be required to select three people(.. not in any case) ..and multiply by 8C3...??

Comment: Yes ever pair of 3 in any arrangement is any 3